# how to solve the below CTE syntax error for the mentioned query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a sample query. I have tried to rewrite it with CTE but some errors occurred. Please check and solve the below query.

actual query;

```
select 
  dt.population, 
  dt.name, 
  c.name 
from 
  (
    select 
      distinct countrycode, 
      name 
    from 
      city
  ) as c, 
  lateral(
    select 
      name, 
      population 
    from 
      city 
    where 
      city.countrycode = c.countrycode 
    order by 
      population desc 
    limit 
      1
  ) as dt\G
```

with CTE

```
 with cte1  as (
    select 
      distinct countrycode, 
      name 
    from 
      city 
  ), 
     cte2  as (
    select 
      name, 
      population 
    from 
      city 
    where 
      cte2.countrycode = cte1.countrycode 
    order by 
      population desc 
    limit 
      1
  ) 
select 
  population, 
  name, 
  name 
from 
  ( select * 

  from cte1,cte2
  ) as a \G
```

error : ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'name'
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cte2.countrycode' in 'where clause'

i have tried put alias for all the table but still am missing something.

Comment: you have `\G`  that is not allowed and your first  query would also generate an error

Comment: you can not use it in that form that will always generate an error

Comment: can you please suggest with some sample values on it

Comment: i know, remove simply the \ and you have an alias or write dt again, there no other error in the code, so i can't help you

Comment: bro just show me what i have to remove and what I have to add ..

Comment: i don't know where i have to make a change

Comment: @nbk can u please suggest some tips to join the first cte column with the second subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this to know where you've define wrong:

```
with cte1  as (
   select 
     distinct countrycode, 
     name 
   from 
     city 
 ), 
    cte2  as (
   select 
     name, 
     population 
   from 
     city 
   where 
     cte2.countrycode = cte1.countrycode /*wrong*/
   order by 
     population desc 
   limit 
     1
 ) 
select 
 population, 
 name, /* wr    */
 name  /*   ong */
from 
 ( select * 

 from cte1,cte2
 ) as a \G /*wrong*/
```

This is a modification that is similar to what you've attempted - without error - but I'm pretty sure it's not what you intended:

```
 with cte1  as (
    select distinct countrycode, name 
    from city 
  ), 
     cte2  as (
    select name, population, countrycode
    from city 
    order by population desc 
    limit 1
  ) 
select 
  population, cte1.name, cte2.name 
from  cte1, cte2
    where 
      cte2.countrycode = cte1.countrycode;
```

Without sample data and expected result, I can only assume that this is what you actually want to do:

```
WITH cte1  AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT countrycode, NAME 
    FROM city 
  ), 
     cte2  AS (
    SELECT NAME, population, countrycode,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY countrycode ORDER BY population DESC) AS Rn
    FROM city 
  )
SELECT 
  cte2.population, cte2.name, cte1.name
FROM  cte1
  JOIN cte2
    ON cte2.countrycode = cte1.countrycode
  WHERE Rn=1;
```

I've tested that with your original query (without cte) [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/llLM0hm1) with some sample data and it does return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that every sub query must have an alias.
So in your second request you have to add an alias for the last subquery

```
select 
population, 
name, 
name 
from 
  ( select * 

  from cte1,cte2
  ) as subqueryName
```

I will assume that the \G is a typo, if not you have to remove it.

EDIT:

I don't really understand the query but this seems to work, can you try it and see if the output is what you expect.

```
    with cte1  as (
 select 
      distinct(c.countrycode), 
      name 
    from 
      city c
  ), 
     cte2  as (
    select 
      name, 
      population 
    from 
      city ct
    order by 
      population desc 
    limit 
      1
  )

    select 
      population, 
      name1, 
      name2
    from 
      ( select cte1.name name1, cte2.name name2, cte2.population
      from cte1,cte2
      ) as nameSubquery
```

Comment: got it bro let me check..   :)

Comment: and how to join the countrycode from the first cte to the second subquery, it can't recognize it.

Comment: I tried to figure out what's you're trying to do without success, can you give more information on what you want to do, to maybe try and come with a better query?

Comment: like normal scans took 1.43 seconds for 4K rows I want to try with CTE how it will work for this.. @Vador

Comment: @vadoor it's almost near but due to the where clause missing the data where wrong can u please check to place the where clause on it ..